# Let $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_a^b g(x) \ dx.$ Find a $c \in [a,b]$ so that $f(c) = g(c)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_a^b g(x) \ dx.$ Prove that there is a $c \in [a,b]$ so that $f(c) = g(c)$.

Not too sure how to proceed with this. I tried moving everything into one integral as follows:

$$
\int_a^b f(x)-g(x) \ dx = 0.
$$

Not quite sure where to go with this. Perhaps I need to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem? Rolles Theorem?

Comment: Consider $F(t)=\int_a^t(f(x)-g(x))dx$.

Comment: we can also assume $f(x)\not= g(x),\forall x\in[a,b]$ , then since $f(x)-g(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ ,we have $f(x)-g(x)>0 $or $<0$ , either way is a contradiction with $\int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)dx=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Consider the function $h$ on $[a,b]$ defined by

$$h(t) = \int_a^t (f(x) - g(x)) \ dx$$

We see that $h(a) = 0$ and $h(b) = 0$. Hence ...

Comment: Voila, just the hint I needed. Thank you, I will accept your answer once SE lets me :)